# Mi programa c++ se crashea y sale antes de terminar

Tags: c++, poo, manejo-de-memoria, g++

Tengo un programa de consola desarrollado en c++ que pide al usuario un número de vendedores a ingresar, una vez introduce el número, se crea un array de objetos de clase "Vendedor"

Después, se inicia un ciclo para preguntar al usuario el nombre de cada vendedor y las ventas del mismo (4 ventas representando 4 meses) para cada uno.

Una vez el usuario, termine de introducir la información de todos los vendedores, se llama a 2 funciones que imprimiran en pantalla el promedio individual y general de las ventas de los vendedores.

La funcion main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
#include <limits>
#include "Vendedor.h"

using namespace std;

float promedioValores(int *valores, int numElementos);
void imprimirPromedioIndividual(Vendedor vendedor);
void imprimirPromedioGeneral(Vendedor *vendedores, int numVendedores);

int main()
{
    int numVendedores = 0;
    string tempNumVendedores;

    cout << "Bienvenido a calculador de promedios de ventas" << endl;

    cout << "Ingrese el numero de vendedores: ";
    cin >> tempNumVendedores;
    cin.ignore();
    numVendedores = stoi(tempNumVendedores);

    Vendedor *vendedores = new Vendedor[numVendedores];

    for (int i = 0; i < numVendedores; i++)
    {
        string nombre;
        cout << "Ingrese el nombre del vendedor " << i + 1 << ": ";
        cin >> nombre;

        // Validate input for nombre (string)
        while (cin.fail())
        {
            cout << "Entrada no válida. Introduzca un nombre válido: ";
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            cin >> nombre;
        }

        vendedores[i].setNombre(nombre);
        int *ventas = new int[4];
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            string ventaTemp;
            cout << "Ingrese las ventas del mes " << j + 1 << ": ";
            cin >> ventaTemp;
            // Validate input for ventas (integer)
            while (cin.fail())
            {
                cout << "Entrada no válida. Introduzca un número válido: ";
                cin.clear();
                cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
                cin >> ventaTemp;
            }
            ventas[j] = stoi(ventaTemp);
        }
        vendedores[i].setVentasCuatrimestrales(ventas, 4);
    }

    // Imprimir los promedios individuales
    for (int i = 0; i < numVendedores; i++)
    {
        imprimirPromedioIndividual(vendedores[i]);
    }

    // Imprimir el promedio general
    imprimirPromedioGeneral(vendedores, numVendedores);

    // Liberar la memoria dinámica
    delete[] vendedores;

    cout << "\nGracias por usar nuestra aplicacion!" << endl;

    cout << "\nPresione cualquier tecla para salir...";

    getch();

    return 0;
}

float promedioValores(int *valores, int numElementos)
{
    cout << "PROMEDIO DE VALORES FUNC CALLED" << endl;
    float suma = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numElementos; i++)
    {
        suma += valores[i];
    }
    return suma / numElementos;
}

void imprimirPromedioIndividual(Vendedor vendedor)
{
    cout << "IMPRIMIR PROMEDIO INDIVIDUAL FUNC CALLED" << endl;
    cout << "El promedio de ventas de " << vendedor.getNombre() << " es: " << promedioValores(vendedor.getVentasCuatrimestrales(), 4) << endl;
}

void imprimirPromedioGeneral(Vendedor *vendedores, int numVendedores)
{
    cout << "IMPRIMIR PROMEDIO GRAL FUNC CALLED" << endl;
    int *ventas = new int[numVendedores * 4];
    for (int i = 0; i < numVendedores; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            ventas[i * 4 + j] = vendedores[i].getVentasCuatrimestrales()[j];
        }
    }
    cout << "El promedio general de ventas es: " << promedioValores(ventas, numVendedores * 4) << endl;
}
```

La clase Vendedor:
Archivo Vendedor.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Vendedor {
  private:
    int* ventasCuatrimestrales;
    std::string nombre;
    int numVentas;
  public:
    
    Vendedor();
    ~Vendedor();
    string getNombre();
    void setNombre(string nombre);
    int* getVentasCuatrimestrales();
    void setVentasCuatrimestrales(int ventas[], int numElementos);
};
```

Archivo Vendedor.cpp

```
#ifndef VENDEDOR_H
#define VENDEDOR_H


#include "Vendedor.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

Vendedor::Vendedor(){}
Vendedor::~Vendedor(){}

string Vendedor::getNombre(){
    return nombre;
}

void Vendedor::setNombre(string nombre){
    this->nombre = nombre;
}

int* Vendedor::getVentasCuatrimestrales(){
    return ventasCuatrimestrales;
}

void Vendedor::setVentasCuatrimestrales(int ventas[], int numElementos) {
    // Deallocate existing memory if not null
    if (ventasCuatrimestrales != nullptr) {
        delete[] ventasCuatrimestrales;
    }

    // Assign new memory
    numVentas = numElementos;
    ventasCuatrimestrales = new int[numElementos];

    // Check for successful memory allocation
    if (ventasCuatrimestrales != nullptr) {
        // Copy the data
        memcpy(ventasCuatrimestrales, ventas, numElementos * sizeof(int));
    } else {
        // Handle memory allocation failure
        cerr << "Error: No se pudo asignar memoria para las ventas." << endl;
        // Perform error handling as needed
    }
}

#endif
```

El error que tengo es que al compilar y correr el ejecutable, introduzco 3 o 4 como número de vendedores, me empieza a pedir la información de cada uno, pero al terminar de introducir la información del Vendedor 2, el programa crashea y hace exit sin terminar el ciclo ni ejecutar las demás operaciones.
No he podido lograr identificar el problema, ya que ni el editor ni el compilador arrojan errores al compilar.
Creo que puede ser problema de administración de la memoria, pero creo que la he utilizado bien, utilizo la memoria dinámica para alocar el array de Vendedores y lo elimino una vez termino de ejecutar todas las funciones que lo usa.

Comment: Si crashea es muy probable que se deba a que intentas acceder a una posición de memoria que no deberías. La causa más común es por no inicializar un puntero. Si te resulta más cómodo utiliza algún contenedor, como `vector`. Por cierto, muestra la entrada que le das al programa para que podamos reproducir el problema.

Comment: Otra sugerencia, en lugar de `stoi` utiliza el operador >> con un `int` directamente. Además, sería raro que obtengas un error al leer un `string`. Es más probable que suceda uno cuando lees un número porque la entrada no sea uno.

Comment: Otra cuestión, por cada iteración reservas memoria que nunca liberas (`ventas`), lo que produce fugas de memoria. Considera liberarla o usar un arreglo `int ventas[4]`.

Comment: Por cierto, los guard clauses van en los archivos .h y no necesitas incluir iostream y string porque incluyes Vendedor.h que ya los incluye.